# LoggerFactory cannot getLogger

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, osgi, loggerfactory

I'm currently implementing a Logger and I'm wondering why the code won't run.
Most of the codes snipets are like these:

```
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

My imported classes:

```
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;
import org.osgi.service.log.LogReaderService;
import org.osgi.service.log.LogService;
import org.osgi.service.log.Logger;
import org.osgi.service.log.LoggerFactory;
```

But I can't seem to use getLogger.

Why is that?

Thanks in advance! [image: No getLogger() classes are available]

Comment: Instead of images, please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Comment: I'm wondering what i'm doing wrong because it doesn't display the getLogger methods

Comment: Can you post the import section of that class?

Comment: @EugenCovaci I edited the post. :)

Comment: If you write `Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());` directly, do you get a compiler error?

Comment: @EugenCovaci I get this error
_Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getLogger(Class) from the type LoggerFactory_

Comment: See my answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.osgi.services/3.7.0/source-code/org/osgi/service/log/LoggerFactory.java) is the source code of `org.osgi.service.log.LoggerFactory`.

As you can see, it's an interface with no static methods therefore this code:

```
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

is simply not valid.

To fix this use `slf4j` as front end (this means replace `org.osgi.service.log.LoggerFactory` import with `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` etc.).

**UPDATE**

If you want to stick with `org.osgi.service.log.LoggerFactory` then follow [this](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-log.html):

Obtain the LoggerFactory instance:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator
{
    private volatile LoggerFactory loggerFactory;

    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception 
    {   
        ServiceReference ref = context.getServiceReference(LoggerFactory.class.getName());
        if (ref != null)
        {
            loggerFactory = (LoggerFactory) context.getService(ref);
        }
    }

    //..
```

Elsewhere in the bundle you can then use the LoggerFactory to get a Logger for any class:

```
Logger logger = loggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);
```

**UPDATE2**

A better alternative would be to get a reference who's service type is LoggerFactory like this:

```
@Reference(service = LoggerFactory.class)
private Logger logger;
```

Comment: But I need to use this LoggerFactory/Logger to change from LogService (since LogService has been depreciated in 1.4) Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Oh. I need to use plugins from eclipse only >_<

Comment: May I know what Foo.class here? Thanks!

Comment: @MelSyGallosa Is the class you want to log.

Comment: Thank you! I got another question. I implemented this but when I used logger.info(message) and used the LogListener. It doesn't seem to go through the LogListener.logged method. (I can't get the logentry) why is that? Thanks

Comment: Please do not ask new questions in the comments. Post a new question in the OSGi topic.

Comment: The code in this answer for obtaining a Logger is very problematic. It is far better to use: `@Reference(service=LoggerFactory.class) private Logger logger`. Please see the presentation linked in @bjhargrave's answer.

Comment: @NeilBartlett If you follow the link I gave, you would find also the service injection as a solution. The two solutions are, actually, equivalent.

Comment: @EugenCovaci They are not equivalent: for example, in the code given in the answer you never release the service. Maybe show the better solution in the actual answer rather than hidden behind a link (which could become invalid in a few years time)?

Comment: @NeilBartlett Done.

Comment: @EugenCovaci JRE needs to be 1.5. I could only use 1.4 due to my current environment

Answer (score 1):

LoggerFactory is an OSGi service. You need to get it from the OSGi service registry. See [my EclipseCon Europe 2018 presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/bjhargrave/the-new-osgi-logservice-14-and-integrating-with-slf4j) for more information.